# open an exe file from another exe file coded in vb

Tags: vb.net, process, executable

i have 2 vb projects that run perfectly. but i have this new requirement. I need to open .exe for project 2 from project 1. both the project have sql server database in back. so they have login/password and customer records that show according to customerid's in both. Now when i click "open project2" button in the first project, it should open the second project with the same customer id as in the first one. how can i do that?

Comment: Does the second application need to run in its own process?  i.e. does it need to have its own lifetime?  Or, are you just needing to access the form from project 1?

Answer (score 0):

The Shell command in VB 6 will open an exe, but I agree with Scott. You might want to separate that form into a common DLL that you can load at runtime from your other app.